# How to call a function using pointer-to-member-function

Tags: c++, function, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

I have a class:

```
class A {
    void test_func_0(int);
    void run();

    typedef void(A::*test_func_t)(int);

    struct test_case_t{
       test_func_t test_func;
    } test_case[100];
};
```

Now I want to call test_func() inside run():

```
void A::run() 
{
    test_case[0].test_func = &test_func_0;
    test_case[0].*(test_func)(1);
}
```

The last line of my code, doesn't work(compile error), no matter what combination I try.

Comment: [How can I avoid syntax errors when calling a member function using a pointer-to-member-function?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html#faq-33.1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this:

```
void A::run() 
{   
    test_case[0].test_func = &A::test_func_0;
    (this->*(test_case[0].test_func))(1);
}
```

Notice that you had 2 errors. The first one was how you formed the member-function-pointer. Note that the only way to do it is to use `&ClassName::FuncName` regardless of whether you're at class scope or not. & is mandatory too.

The second is that when you call a member via a member function pointer, you must explicitly specif y the object (of type A in your case) on which to call the member function. In this case you must specify `this` (and since this is a pointer we use `->*` rather than `.*`)

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
(this->*test_case[0].test_func)(1);
```

Answer (score -1):

Member function call using pointer-to-member-function:

```
 test_case[0].test_func = &A::test_func_0; //note this also!
(this->*test_case[0].test_func)(1);
```

Demo : http://www.ideone.com/9o8C4

Comment: test_func is an A:: member, not a test_case_t member.

Comment: @Erik: Yeah. I noticed. Actually I was testing it at ideone. So corrected and posted the link to Ideone also!