# Not able to call a function using function pointer

Tags: c++, function-pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to call a function using pointer-to-member-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218903/how-to-call-a-function-using-pointer-to-member-function)

Analyzer.h

```
class Analyzer
{
public :

    void viku();
    void Bibek();
    void vivek();
    void (Analyzer::*point)();

    Analyzer(){

    }
    ~Analyzer(){

    }

};
```

Analyzer.cpp

```
    using namespace std     
    #include"Analyzer.h"
    void Analyzer::viku(){
        cout<<"Hello viku";
    }
    void Analyzer::vivek(){
        point =&Analyzer::viku; 
        Bibek();   
    }
    void Analyzer::Bibek(){
           point();//Errror
        cout<<"Bibek";
    }
```

During compilation it shows the following error:

> error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments.

Can anyone please tell me how to avoid this?

Comment: You should read the chapter in your book about pointers-to-member-functions, because that is not a normal function pointer. -1 for no prior research.

Comment: I read it but still not able to find out that's why i have posted this here .
According to me i have done everything correct
1-both the function pointer and function's signature is same . and the calling convention too . Then where i am getting the problem ?

Comment: not related to your problem, but important: Avoid using `using namespace` in header files, better yet: don't use it at all. It might cause naming conflicts.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: It looks like he understands the difference, but not that `point();` doesn't work from a member function where `viku();` would. +1 for a reasonable question.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Please hover over the downvote icon and notice that lack of research is a reason to downvote. How to use pointers-to-member-functions is covered in any good C++ book and thus should not need to be asked _again_ here. Or, if nothing else, it's a duplicate.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Instead of so many discussion can you please tell me (and of course other c++ learner)what is the error  here ?

Comment: Got it . i have to use (this->*point)();

Comment: @Learner: It is explained in your C++ book.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit::No . I have c++ complete reference 3rd edition . Please ask the person before giving down votes in such scenario.

Comment: @Learner: Page 339. Please read the book before posting questions in such a scenario.

Comment: Thanks . But it is inside main function . But my post is for inner call . I am not so much good in c++, so may be that's a reason because of which i could not able to relate both of it . But later i found that solution .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pointers to member functions are different than normal function pointer. You need an instance to call them:

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
  int foo()
  {
      std::cout << "A::foo here, you can have 42" << std::endl;
      return 42;
  }
};

int main ()
{
  int (A::* point)() = &A::foo;
  A a;

  (a.*point)();
}
```

In your case, you'd need to do something like the following:

```
(this->*point)()
```